# Permission issue when using include()

Tags: php, linux, centos, chmod

I just changed to a production environment so I'm setting up everything, and I just bumped into a **Permission Denied** error (while using `include()`)that I am pretty sure it is caused by the permissions. The thing is I have never used an actual server before, I have always use cPanel hosting, so I am no expert dealing with **chmod** and these things.

The folder containing all files I'll be `include()`ing has the following permissions `drwxr-xr-x`.

I'm pretty sure `w` stands for write, `r` for read and `x` for execute. But I have no Idea why does it have 3 columns (separated by '-') and how to change it using chmod. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There's probably a disconnect between the user account that your web services are running under and the file owner. You'll likely need to `chown` to change ownership of the include files to match the account your server is running under.

Comment: uhmm not sure what you mean. But the directory that I want my include() to read is in /home/user1/ which is a non-root user's home folder.

Comment: That's generally not a good place to keep files for your web services. You want them in a folder at least relative to your web root. See [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/125865/finding-out-what-user-apache-is-running-as) for info on your apache services account. Say it's `www-root`, you then need to `chown www-root -R /path/to/includes`

Comment: `/home/user1` dorectory is normally not readable by web server. if you check the permission for that directory it most probably will be `drwx------`. so any directory/file under that is also not readable by web server. You may need to add read and execute permission for others to that directory which is **not** safe.

Comment: Also you may hit `SeLinux` permission issues and need to add special permissions if you try to keep the web files outside `/var/www/html` folder.

Comment: I'm confused now, I put those files there cause the PHP framework I'm using said that you want to keep PHP Classes out of DocumentRoot

Comment: You can keep them inside `/var/www/html` even if you web documentroot is `/var/www/html/yoursite.com` -- just reference them with the relative path `../includes` or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved, created a group and chowned and chmoded the folder to it.